# Sending $row['id'] through a form to another PHP using a button

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to create a page that can toggle devices on and off, a smart home kind of thing.

The code looks as follows:

```
<form method="post" action="toggle.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo {$row['id']};?>"/>
        <button type="submit" name="on" id="on" class="btn btn-success">On</button>
        <button type="submit" name="off" id="off" class="btn btn-danger">Off</button>
</form>
```

This is the form that sends either "on" or "off" to toggle.php.

Toggle.php looks like this:

```
<?php 
include('devices.php');

if (isset($_POST["on"])){

        mysqli_query($mysqli,"UPDATE devices SET status = 'On' WHERE id = '$row['id']'");       
}
if(isset($_POST["off"])){

        mysqli_query($mysqli,"UPDATE devices SET status = 'Off' WHERE id = '$row['id']'");

}
?>
```

My question is: how do i get what's in `$row['id']` in the form to get sent to toggle.php and then be used to update the status of the device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the data you are posting to the toggle.php with the superglobal `$_POST`, just as you did with $_POST['off'] for example.

```
mysqli_query($mysqli,"UPDATE devices SET status = 'On' WHERE id = '".$_POST['id']."'");
```

Quick note: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections, you might want to learn about them here: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Hey Paul, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. I'm certain that i've done something wrong somewhere. If i, instead of ".$_POST['id']." insert a ID number the code does work. Weird.

Comment: Could you `var_dump($_POST['id'])` before executing the query to make sure your id is actually in there?

Comment: I tried that and `var_dump` returned `string(16)`. What could that mean? I don't have any device with id 16.

Comment: Then we just found the problem. How do you retrieve the devices (probably how does your query look like?) so you can display them like `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo {$row['id']};?>"/>`?

Comment: I got it working now! Changed the value of `<input>` from `value="<?php echo {$row['id']};?>"` to `value="{$row['id']}"` and it worked together with your first answer, thank you!