# How can I send a row ID to a linked page using a submit button using HTML and PHP?

Tags: php, html, forms

The code below loops through a database table (accommodation) using mysqli_query and for each row creates a summary card to display an image and row info (name, ID, location, and price). 14 summary cards are displayed.

A submit button links to a 'more info' page.

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM accommodation";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    if ($result){
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){ 
            while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                ?>                      
                <div class="summary-card">      
                    <img src="<?php echo $fetch['main_image'] ?>" >                  
                    <p> <?php echo $fetch['name'], $fetch['ID'] ?> </p>
                    <p> <?php echo $fetch['location'] ?> </p>
                    <p>from <?php echo $fetch['price'] ?> </p>
                    <form  action="info.php" method="get">
                        <input type="submit" name="<?php echo $fetch['ID'] ?>" value="More info" >
                    </form>
                </div>
                <?php
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Can accommodationID be sent when submitting?

This would facilitate having **just one** 'more info' page and then being able to populate that page based on the table row ID that was passed when clicking on the related submit.

**I've seen examples showing how to send a row ID to a linked page ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43396371/pass-on-a-row-id-onto-another-page-in-php), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50314340/sending-rowid-through-a-form-to-another-php-using-a-button), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871858/php-pass-variable-to-next-page)) but not when the initial content was created using a loop.**

So far I am able to append an ID to the target URL after clicking using the "get" method. However, if I try to print the ID using $_SESSION['accommodationID'] I get the ID relating to the last loop (14). If I use $_GET['accommodationID']I get an undefined index error.

New to PHP (procedural) and have honestly done my best trying for a few days before posting.

Comment: You could add accomodationID to the form within the loop using a hidden input, as the question does in your [second example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50314340/sending-rowid-through-a-form-to-another-php-using-a-button). This should not be changed by the fact it's in a loop.
Using this method should allow you to access it from `$_GET['accommodationID']` where you couldn't before.
[`$_SESSION`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session) is entirely seperate and not to be confused with [`$_GET`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get) and forms.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways of doing it

**Using a param**

```php
<form  action="info.php?<?php echo $fetch['ID'];?>" method="get">
  <input type="submit" name="<?php echo $fetch['ID'];?>" value="More info" >
</form>
```

And you use a $_GET to obtain the value.

**Using a hidden input**

```php
<form  action="info.php" method="get">
  <input class="hidden" type="text" name="ID" value="<?php echo $fetch['ID'];?>">
  <input type="submit" name="<?php echo $fetch['ID'];?>" value="More info" >
</form>
```

And look at the hidden value of 'ID'.  Note that this name does not have to be unique as only one will be posted. And use a style in css to hide the 'hidden'

```css
input.hidden {display:none}
```